# Why is 会社へ行く仕方 ungrammatical/weird?

Tags: grammar, nuances

I was looking at the [GOO thesaurus entry](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/thsrs/14733/meaning/m0u/%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95/) for 方法/仕方/手段, and in the comparison table, it indicates that 会社へ行く方法 and 会社へ行く手段 are grammatical, but 会社へ行く仕方 is not. Why is this?

Certainly, I understand that 手段 is more focused on the materials needed for some purpose, and 仕方 is more like focused on the a series of actions themselves. But still, certainly both should be valid when talking about getting to work, right?

The others I think I understand. 話の手段 would be weird because it would be like a tongue and vocal chords, and 話の方法 would sound more like something complicated logical rather than an intuitive art. 連絡の仕方がない would sound like one doesn't have some sort of procedure to contact, which doesn't make sense unless one is thinking about military codes or something. And 通勤の…を再考する was explained early on in the entry for why all could be used and what the nuances would be. Please correct me if I'm wrong about any of these though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

「会社への行き方」 works. I feel that, since 仕方 is originally derived from し（連用形 of する） + 方【かた】, it is ungrammatical for it to connect to a verb.

Compare:

- 水を飲む → 水の飲み方【かた】
- 会社へ行く → 会社への行き方【かた】
- 話をする → 話の仕方【しかた】
- あいさつ(を)する → あいさつの仕方【しかた】